# How to merge adjacent polygons automatically

Tags: attributes, qgis, nearest-neighbor

I have a vector file which contains adjacent polygons and I want to merge or 'dissolve' it into one based only on their adjacency. Not having a common attribute field does not allow use of 'dissolve' feature. I do not want to dissolve non-adjacent polygons because later I want to filter features such as selection of features with > 100 sq. km and such. I have used QGIS's Join Attributes by nearest feature with a maximum distance of 0 to find feature adjacency.

Please follow the link below to download the polygon shapefile. This is just part of a large vector file. I want to do it automatically, manually doing it is my last resort.

[image]

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1G_irrjmzq19LljMtELT-B0tpX9gHfqD7?usp=sharing

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the `disolve` tool on the vector menu

Comment: The demo file that I have shared is only a small part of a large file. I cannot use the "dissolve" tool function because I have to "filter" the polygons based on their size such as > 100 sq. km.

Comment: maybe you need to clarify your question

Comment: I have tried to clarify it with edits in my question.